# Identifying/Listing COM Objects and Properties from third party software

Tags: delphi, com, automation

I'm trying to design an application that can identify COM objects and their properties on any different application. This is my first time attempting to do so, and I'm not sure where to start even. Ideally, it would be made using Delphi XE2, but I'm open to suggestions.

If I have the CLSID, is there any way to "scan" a running application for what objects were based on it? Or, going another way, is there a better way to list/find active objects in any running application?

Any help is deeply appreciated, as well as any directions towards good documentation on the subject.

**Edit:** The issue is actually finding out the COM objects in any other application, listing properties and whatever else I need has already been answered in other questions.

Comment: Inject code to other application that would call GetActiveObject for all known application objects in the system. Sorry, I can't think of anything else..

Comment: Are you tried the [GetRunningObjectTable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684004%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function?

Comment: I've had limited success with ROT, since apparently the application must explicitly register objects, which is not always the case.

Comment: @M.P.R. - Would you care to elaborate on your limited success. AFAIK, even if all servers were required to register in ROT, an object in ROT does not even have to be bound by a client. If it is bound, it won't supply any information about the client(s) either.

Comment: @Sertac Akyuz, I should had made myself clear, I've got some applications show up on my ROT, but after noticing many applications were missing, and finding out that they had to be explicitly registered there, I figured looking up the ROT would not do.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no way to scan for running COM objects. As soon as they are instantiated - they are just pieces of memory referenced by something else (member interface pointer variables etc).

Sometimes objects are put on Running Objects Table (`ROT`) and you can retrieve them from there, as already suggested in comments. This attributes for, let's say, <1% of COM object instances, but maybe you are lucky enough to chase for exactly those.

The only way I can think of is hook COM object instantiation in so that you intercept creation and then be able to track your own list of existing instances. This is not an easy way though too (and also it is most likely to be unsafe).

To achieve this you need to either register your class object in the context of running process for the `CLSID` of your interest and have your class factory receive the instantiation calls. Or, hook `CoCreateInstance` API, such as with [`Detours`](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/detours/).

Once you are hooking instantiation you have pointers at the moment of object creation and you again need to do something with them. You would want to forward those instantiation calls to the original API, then to track life time of the instances - if you put an extra reference to the object you are likely to alter the original behavior of the application. Otherwise, you have no control to intercept COM object release. Sometimes the COM classes can be created aggregated and you can more or less cleanly embed the original instance in your COM object.

All in all, in general the task does not seem feasible to implement. Having specific `CLSID` of interest, with a certain luck and quite some effort you might be successful in doing this though.

Comment: Perhaps I'm approaching this the wrong way and over complicating things? I have to be able to read a few labels and edits at an application developed in VB6, but I have no access to sources codes. To do so, would you say I still would have to hook instantiations?

Comment: @Roman, is it possible to get information from ROT on which (client) process invoked an entry (if any)? If not your second paragraph is irrelevant to the question, as the question asks how to know what objects a particular process instantiated.

Comment: @MPR, my opinion is that scanning memory for instances is definitely the wrong way. Given that you have some signature of the instance, the heap the instance located on etc it still looks like extremely painful process. But you seem to be knowing a lot more about your objects - are they ActiveX controls? If they are, esp. windowed, then you can find windows of the controls, and if they are ATL-based, which is likely, you perhaps can use ATL messages to obtain interfaces from `HWND`s, and if this hook works out - you are good to move on enumerating properties through well known interfaces.

Comment: @Sertac, sometimes clients put entries on ROT indicating the process identifier. ROT is actually not related to the question at all, but I had to mention this because of other comments suggesting it might be helpful.

Comment: @Roman, I know a little about the objects I want in one application, but the goal would be to extend it to any application out there. I'm not sure if they are ActiveX controls, is there something I could do if they aren't? Also, I am a bit new to Stack Overflow, should I post another question asking what would be the best way to "Read" information in other applications regardless of object types?

Comment: @M.P.R. If I was you I would ask a second question on SO with exactly what you need to do (ie read labels and edits) - you might get some interesting suggestions